# Save document as PDF without page breaks from Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, pdf

Is there a way to make Google Docs save a document as a PDF but without splitting it into multiple pages?  I understand that sticking to a certain page size is important for printing, but for the PDF I'm making it's not necessary and even distracting to have multiple pages.

I can't simply use a larger standard page size such as Tabloid, as the amount of content would still result in multiple pages.

[2024-01] Google Docs now includes pageless mode however that doesn't seem to carry over to the PDF.

How can I convert a pageless Google document to a single page/pageless PDF?

Answer (score 3):

Here's my workaround:

1. From Google Drive export your document as a HTML web page

- File > Download as > Web Page (.html)

2. Use Sejda's [**HTML to PDF converter**](https://www.sejda.com/html-to-pdf) and the handy '**One long page**' size option.

- Go to https://www.sejda.com/html-to-pdf
- Select the **Convert HTML files** tab and then upload your HTML file
- Click **Convert HTML to PDF**

By default the page size is '**One long page**'. Can change it under **More options**.

[image: Sample Google Docs document converted to a long page PDF]

If your Google doc contains images then when exporting to HTML you'll get a zip file. You can't upload a zip file to convert it to PDF, only the HTML file so it does't work great in that case.

Disclosure: I'm a Sejda developer.

Comment: This works well for text only, but do you know how we might include images with this workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Google Docs conversion is usually more permissive than it's own menu's would suggest. Have Libre-Office spit out 3m (its' max) tall pages and convert. MS Word will not go beyond 22 inches. Here is the converted result [template](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16cC3V8abiXh8vDcwYDYF7b9NBRcE_pIzNg56C6-ES2o/edit?usp=sharing). Maybe if you tweak the internal structure of the ODT file (unzip the odt, edit the style.xml, edit pagesize, rezip) you might be able to stretch this even further.

As you mentioned and probably understand PDF is a Printer Definition file. This is more a PDF question (or a word processor question) than a Google Docs question. The disclaimers I would like to add... No wordprocessor should allow for what you are asking. PDF's are page based. Continuous scrolling (no on-screen pagebreaks) is and should be a viewer setting. But hey, because you shouldn't doesn't mean you couldn't. Right? Maybe you can change paper sizes in a PDF editor, like Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround I found that may work for other programs but I used Pages on Mac.

- On Google Docs, Export to docx
- Open the docx in Pages
- Page Setup
- Increase page height to accommodate content (8.5" x 20" for example)
- Export to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `File -> Page Setup` and choose a larger `Paper size`. For my purposes I used `Tabloid` which is much larger than the default `Letter`.