# Export pageless Google doc (with images) to PDF

Tags: google-docs, pdf

I'm looking to save my pageless Google Doc as a .PDF file. I have tried the workaround described [HERE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/112736/251500) which essentially works by saving the Google Doc as HTML, then using a web service to convert to pageless PDF, however this method does not allow for images to be included.

I am open to all kinds of workarounds, as I am desperate to get this done correctly.

Also, this post is NOT a duplicate of [THIS](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/google-docs-get-pdf-without-page-breaks) thread, as my question is distinct in that it needs to include images, not simply text as posted in the other question.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried opening the Doc in your browser and using the [html-pdf browser extension](https://www.sejda.com/html-to-pdf#browser-extension)?

Comment: @BlindSpots yes, thanks for asking. When I try that it says "Unable to Load" Try it yourself - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mSQ0LtigZ7s28Uiyx0mT2QZdhjXaXTxVmdcnSBCWGLM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You can first `publish` the Doc [File > Share > Publish to web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coJWz.png "view image") then the extension will work.  You will need to make the images the same width as the text area or they will overlap, and may still not be happy with the output. This is an example of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thank you this seems to work, however I am not able to reconcile the image width difference. When I look at the images on my document before publishing they seem fine, so I am at a loss of how to resize them. Indeed it is an XY problem.

Comment: I've got an idea I'll try when I'm home tonight.

Comment: Tested [solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/170310/) successfully.  For a one-off you can use the web URL's in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a variation on the workaround you [linked to](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/112736/) with a fix for your missing images problem.

The issue is that Sejda's HTML-to-PDF tool can only understand the paths for images that are hosted on the web.  My workaround (workaround for a [workaround](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/112736/)) is simply to temporarily host the images on the web.

For example, when you download your Doc as HTML you end up downloading a ZIP archive.  When you extract the ZIP archive, you note that it contains one HTML file in addition  to a folder labeled `images` containing your 6 images (5 png, 1 jpg):

- images/image1.png
- images/image2.`jpg`
- images/image3.png
- images/image4.png
- images/image5.png
- images/image6.png

These images are linked in the HTML document in image tags similar to `<img src="images/image5.png">`

#### Instructions

1. Temporarily upload each of the images in turn, and note their new web URLs.
2. Open the HTML file in a text editor, and perform a "Replace All" using the local image path as the `FIND` string, and the web URL as the `REPLACE` string.
3. Once that has been completed for each of the 6 images, save the HTML document.
4. Open the HTML document in a web browser and use [Sejda's HTML-to-PDF extension](https://www.sejda.com/html-to-pdf#browser-extension) or alternatively upload the file to Sejda's HTML-to-PDF converter, or even copy and paste the HTML code.

| Find All (local image path) | Replacement (Image URL) |
| --- | --- |
| `images/image1.png` | https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGvvJ.png |
| `images/image2.jpg` | https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHYEZ.jpg |
| `images/image3.png` | https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDubj.png |
| `images/image4.png` | https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SPCz.png |
| `images/image5.png` | https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkz6g.png |
| `images/image6.png` | https://i.stack.imgur.com/76lMJ.png |

Comment: I will accept this as answered (thank you), but there is no way I am going to do this each time one of my dozens of tutorials is updated, as they are updated often. I was hoping for an easy way to do this. Thanks for the workaround.